# Unable to connect to feedback.sandbox.apple.com via tcp client in pushsharp

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Unable to connect to the feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com with port number 2196.
Opened the ports (5223, 2915, 2916, 443) in windows firewall with TCP/SSL.

Tried connecting via telnet too, but did not help.

Getting the below exception

```
Service Exception: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Exception (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party
did not properly respond after a period of`enter code here` time, or established connection faile
d because connected host has failed to respond 17.172.232.45:2196
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at PushSharp.Apple.FeedbackService.Run(ApplePushChannelSettings settings, Can
cellationToken cancelToken) in d:\Sample Apps\Push Notification\PushSharp-master
\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\FeedbackService.cs:line 60
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__1(Object sta
te) in d:\Sample Apps\Push Notification\PushSharp-master\PushSharp-master\PushSh
arp.Apple\ApplePushService.cs:line 51

Failure: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> The maximum number of Send attempts
 to send the notification was reached! -> {"aps":{"alert":"Hello World!","badge"
:7,"sound":"sound.caf"}}
```

Also, this does not need certificate to connect to sandbox, so why this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You do need a development certificate from the Apple Developer portal to connect to sandbox. But I don't know if you need to use it to connect to feedback.sandbox.apple.

I can't seem to find a straight answer on this whether feedback services still works. I think APNS Feedback services are now deprecated. This could be why you're getting this error.

[Does APNS Feedback service no longer exist as per new APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630585/does-apns-feedback-service-no-more-exist-as-per-new-apis)

[APNS Feedback Service - is it still alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659089/apns-feedback-service-is-it-still-alive)