# APNS Feedback Service - is it still alive?

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

When Googleing for `ios device token expiration` topic you'll find many notices about `Apple Feedback Service`. It's for polling of `device token expiration` so when `Feedback Service` told that particular `device token` is expired it means that there is no chance to deliver `push-notification` to that `device token`. We should mark them as `expired`.

Now I couldn't find any `Feedback Service` mention in actual `Apple` docs.
Is this service deprecated? If so, why [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp), [pushd](https://github.com/rs/pushd) libraries still use it? And if so, what to do next? Read send status as on `Google` and `Microsoft` platforms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630585/does-apns-feedback-service-no-more-exist-as-per-new-apis

Comment: Thank you for fast response.

Comment: @chedabob: That is only talking about how the new APNS API doesn't have a feedback service. Nothing about the old APNS API.

Comment: So I guess the service is deprecated. Does anybody know if it still works with PushSharp? Are we just supposed to go off of the Http status code 410 then?

Comment: Current stable version 2.x supports only deprecated feedback service, the main developer is working on new api support in 3.x develop branch.

Comment: Guys, the feedback service is on the last page of the APNS docs in the Local and Remote Notifications PDF.  It's the last thing after discussing how to use APNS.  Look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH106-SW4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: Fry, is it you?